# Is League of Legends haram or halal to play

Tags: halal-haram, shirk, game

I am very curious if this game is haram to play it has music that can be disabled and nudity in the log screen that can be hided but there are skin of characters that are named such as "god fist lee sin" or "god king darius" but I can not choose them and play other characters, does that make the game haram or if I dont choose them it's fine?

Answer (score 0):

I dont have any exact answers - im not scholar aswell. But i'll explain important issues with it. There's two very big issues with this game - in-game there are so called "gods" (Auzubillah) made up by developers. Even though you can ignore it and avoid - there is second problem - if you defeat 7 or 8 enemies without dying yourself - game calls you "god-like" (Auzubillah)
These two things are enough for me to avoid League Of Legends. I won't touch any game that calls me like that.

Answer (score -1):

IMO yes because there is magic in the game where you know it’s haram and the characters with name you know what lol you don’t have to choose them because what if you 1v1 a player and then he has that character this is a no go my friend be on the safe side Allah Insha’Allah may reward you for it.

Comment: Please do not give your opinion. This website is about answering questions with logic or proofs. Also, the magic isn’t the bad here, it’s all fictional, it’s a video game. The bad here is the nudity not the magic nor the music.